# Deriving y'=y and z'=z from symmetry

Tags: geometry, physics, symmetry, special-relativity

Consider the following system

[image]

It's clear that the Galilean transformation from the frame S to S' in this case is given by:

$$\begin{align} 
x' &= x-vt \\
y' &= y \\
z' &= z \\
t' &= t
\end{align}$$

I'm asked to justify the second and third equations above using a symmetry argument.  But I don't really see how the equations are even derivable -- they just seem like the obvious equations describing the system to me.

The only thing I can think is to say that, because $S(t=0) = S'(t'=0)$ and because the motion of $S'$ relative to $S$ is just a movement at the constant speed $v$ in the $x$-direction, there's no displacement in the $y$ or $z$ direction and hence $y(t=0)=y'(t'=0) \implies y(t)=y'(t')$ for all time $t = t'$.  And likewise for $z$.  But I don't think that counts as a symmetry argument (or does it?  I'm not totally sure what a "symmetry" argument means -- it usually means use cylindrical or spherical symmetry to reduce the number of coordinates/ equations describing a system).  What type of argument is being asked for here?

BTW, this is exercise 1 from page 45 of Resnick's *Introduction to Special Relativity*.

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry often means just "identifying the structure in common between different things". I'm not sure this is what they want, given that I also feel "it's obvious" -- but it's one answer you could give: consider the case where $v = 0$. What happens to the equation for $x$? Now consider what must happen when I compose transformations, going once $+v$ then $-v$. Using the $x$ coordinate equation, we see that $x$ must be unchanged afterwards, which makes sense we're in the same frame as before. Similarly $y$ and $z$ must be unchanged.

But what if we go $+v$, then *flip our definition of $x$ to $-x$*, and then go $+v$ again? We return to the rest frame. But $y$ and $z$ can't be affected by just flipping our definition of $x$. So they must have experienced whatever transformation goes with $+2v$. Since they're unchanged, it stands that any boost in the $x$ direction can't affect $y$ or $z$.

*Note*: The slight caveat with this argument is that requires that physics has mirror symmetry. For most physical processes this is true, but in some cases it is not; notably weak quantum mechanics. Or some physical processes with a chiral medium, such as discussing optics in a water-dextrose solution. You could then theoretically have something where boosting in the $x$ direction causes $y$ and $z$ to rotate slightly clockwise. When we flip $x$ and boost backwards, it causes $y$ and $z$ to rotate counterclockwise back again, since they're sensitive to the left- or right-handedness of the coordinate system.